# Where to store UI information

Tags: database-design, user-interface, architecture

Suppose we have a form used to edit Widgets. A given Widget has an Attribute. The value of that Attribute (A) can be one of a stored list of Attributes (1, 2, 3). Our list of Attributes is used across several Widget types.

Now, from a data perspective, a given Widget can have an Attribute A of any of the list (it can contain the value 1, 2, or 3). However, our business rules dictate that Widget type X cannot contain the value 1 in Attribute A.

My question is, where do I store information that the form will use to populate the list for Attribute A?

Now, it happens that I am using a different form for Widgets X, Y, and Z, but in theory, we could have to address this on the same form. I can store it on the Widget class, or on the Attribute class, but I feel this is not representative of actual object information (the same way "sushi" is not a valid Food of the Dog class, even though it is a perfectly valid Food, it does nothing to describe the Dog). How would you populate the Food list on the Edit Dog form? I need the approved list information to be editable, and not need to re-deploy code, as users are fickle and eventually someone will want to feed their Dog sushi.

Writing this in C#, but I feel this question is pretty language-agnostic.

*Added after response from user Blueberry:*

Thanks, maybe my description wasn't clear. Imagine a Widgets table, an Attributes table, and a Widget_Attributes table that would be an x-ref containing the Attributes *allowed* to be assigned to a given property of a Widget. That's one way it could be done, but seems like a code smell as it could result in an x-ref table for each property on the Widget. So I'm looking for a way to populate a control with only the Attribute values allowable for that type of widget.

The idea in the lead right now would be to add a flags enum to each Attribute record that would indicate what Widgets that Attribute is valid for. In the Dog-Food example, the Food sushi would have an EatenBy enum property that would have a value of 1, where the enum would be defined as Human = 1, Dog = 2, Cat = 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a widget which has different behaviour based on the data that is selected by a user in another part of your control?

Firstly, I dont think there is a right or wrong answer for this.  It really depends how close to the UI the logic is.  If its in any way business logic, I'd keep it out of the control (like say a combo box), however, if its purely UI (like say the logic in a datetime picker), it would go into the control.

By the sounds of it though, from what I'm gathering from your specific case, it is closer the the first one.  If you are using an MVC architecture I would probably have this logic closer to my model than my view or controller.

I guess this is just a more complex version of what say, a ComboBox would do, I would say that certainly in order to keep this generic, it would not be part of the form or control itself as that would be quite a specific case.  Probably true that only you will be using the code, but in general coding practice, keeping this detail outside your controls will allow for better code reuse at the very least.

Depending on the complexity of the data, what you could do is to create an object which has all this data inside it, create this on the model and pass this to the widget so that it knows what to do when various components of your control's data is selected by the user.  I.E. An object that the control will understand but is generated on the model.  Its not strictly necessary to call back to the model if the data is static enough, this would be passed in possibly on initialisation.

Hope that helps, just my view.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but points for being the only person to step up. Thanks!